# Subset a Data Frame Based on All Combinations and Sub-combinations of Factor Variables

Tags: r, combinatorics

I need to subset a data.frame based on all combinations an sub-combinations of multiple columns of factor variables. Additionally the number of columns factor variables may change so the method needs to be flexible in accepting different numbers of attributes. I can figure out how to create the combinations of variables in a simple example but don't have a good way to subset the data.frame efficiently. Any thoughts?

```
#setup an example data.frame
a <- c("a", "b", "b", "b", "e")
b <- c("b", "c", "b", "b", "f")
c <- c("c", "d", "b", "b", "g")
df <- data.table(a = a, b = b, c = c)


#build a data.frame of unique combos to subset on 
df_unique <- df[!duplicated(df), ]
df_combos <- data.table()
for(i in 1:ncol(df_unique)){
  for(x in 1:ncol(df_unique)){
    df_sub <- df_unique[,i:x, with = F]
    df_combos <- rbind(df_combos, df_sub, fill = T)
  }
}

df_combos <- df_combos[!duplicated(df_combos), ]
rm(df_unique)


#create a loop to build the subsets
combos_out <- data.table()
for(i in 1:nrow(df_combos)){
  df_combos_sub <- df_combos[i, ]
  df_combos_sub <- df_combos_sub[,which(unlist(lapply(df_combos_sub, function(x)!all(is.na(x))))),with=F]
  df_sub <- merge(df, df_combos_sub, by = colnames(df_combos_sub))  
  #interesting code here that performs analysis on the subsets
}
```

Comment: Please provide your desired output for your example. It is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: Your use of "subset" makes me wonder if you really mean "sample". If you just want various statistics on subsets, then the `aggregate` or `tapply` should deliver useful results. You should at the very least clarify what a desired outcome from this process might be.

Comment: Given all of the different possible combinations of factor variables I want to subset the original data.frame (df in this case with the subset df_sub) to perform analysis on it. If sample is the preferred methodology I'm happy to use that =)

If you run the df_combos loop you can see that it is generating a number of combinations of the factor variables. Which should be exhaustive or close to it that the table is then subset on.